# Android:How to get the name of the background image of ImageView

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the background image name of the ImageView.

Appreciate your time.

Thanks

Comment: String BgName = yourImageView.getBackground().toString();

Answer (score 1):

No, because the background image does not necessarily have a name. If you are the one setting the background image, you would need to keep track of the name yourself.

Comment: I'm getting drawable from SharedPreferences using:               String text = app_preferences.getString("key", "null"); I want to set this string in layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable). Do you know how to convert string to drawable.

Comment: @Kavi: What do you mean by "convert string to drawable"? Is the string a path to a file? Is the string the name of a resource? Is the string something else, and if so, what is it?